# Reset I2C connection with arduino as slave

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c, raspberrypi

I am currently using I2C serial communications with arduino as slave and raspberry pi as the master. I am sending sensor data from arduino to raspberry pi. I need to reset the I2C connection once the sensor readings cross a threshold. I tried setting the TWCR =0 but it throws a Error 121 Remote I/O error on the raspberry pi when I do that. I also read that one way is to set TWCR =0, but for this I need to execute the Wire.begin(), Wire.onRequest(), and Wire.onReceive() again. Can you please tell me how to run these again since they are put in setup function. Does it mean I need to restart the Arduino program again? Or can I put these in void loop()? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why do you need to reset the I2C connection? And you can use all the functions of the library wherever you want

Comment: Hi Chrisl, I want to reset the connection because I don't want Arduino to send any more values to the master once the sensor readings cross a threshold value. Is there a better way to implement it?

Answer (score 2):

You have a misconception about how I2C works. Unlike Serial (UART) I2C is a strictly master-slave interface. The slave cannot do anything without the master, since only the master controls the clock. Thus you don't need to reset the I2C interface to stop the transmission from the slave to the master.

When the master requests data from the slave the following happens: First the master sends the address of the targeted slave, including the direction bit set for "reading from slave". The slave with this address reacts with an acknowledgement (ACK) and start to transmit one byte. This byte get's acknowledged by the master. When the master decides, that it has received enough data, it does not acknowledge (NACK), which let's the slave stop it's transmission. Then the master sends a STOP condition to stop the I2C transmission.

I don't know, how you implemented the I2C communication on the Pi. Normally, when you initiate a read transaction from the master, you provide a number of bytes, that you want to request from the slave. The I2C module/library will then request data from the slave, until is has received all the requested bytes.

Thus you don't need to reset the I2C connection on the Arduino. The master totally controls the communication. When you end the transmission on the master, the slave cannot send further data.

Setting TWCR to zero in the middle of transaction will disrupt the I2C communication protocol. Thus you get an error on the Pi, that states an error in the I2C communication protocol. Just use the correct implementation of the I2C protocol to end the transmission correctly.